# Prove or disprove the following statement

Tags: discrete-mathematics

If $x$ is an irrational number and $r$ is a non-zero rational number then $x/r$ is an irrational number
I do not know how to approach this problem

Answer (score 5):

Hint : Suppose $r$ and $\frac{x}{r}$ are rational and look at $x=r\times \frac{x}{r}$

Comment: Im sorry I still have some confusion

Comment: The left side ($x$) is irrational, the right side a product of rational numbers, therefore rational. But the right side is also $x$. You arrive at a contradiction. Therefore the assumption is false.

Answer (score 1):

Peter's answer is good.

An alternative is let $r = \frac m n$; m and n integers. Then $\frac x  r = x \frac n m$.  If  $x \frac n m = M/N$; M and N integers, then $x = \frac {Mm}{Nn}$.  Hmmmm.

Answer (score 0):

Alternately, proof by contradiction:

If $r$ is rational and $s = x/r$ is rational, then there exist integers $a,b,c,d$ such that $r = a/b$ and $s = c/d$.  Then $x = rs = ac/bd$ is rational.